# Sort bars inside the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

For this plot

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(stock = c("google", "google", "amazon", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "yahoo", "yahoo"), status = c("open", "close", "open", "buy", "close", "open", "buy", "close"), category = c("daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily", "daily"), price = c(330379.36, 52324.62, 545240.22, 192574.83, 46721.34, 477658.62, 146724.44, 42721.78))
```

and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(fill=stock, y=price, x= status)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
    ggtitle("Daily") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0)) +
    geom_text(aes(label=price), position = position_dodge(width= 1), vjust=1) + coord_flip()
```

How is possible to sort from higher to lower the bars inside every status?

Comment: ````y=reorder(price,status)```` should do it

Comment: Please see updated answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry . The code in my comment will change the price column into categorical type, which will be evident once you see the axis. Adding the `group` argument does it.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes( y=price, x= status,fill=stock,group=rank(price))) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  ggtitle("Daily") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=price), position = position_dodge(width= 1), vjust=1) + coord_flip()
```

[image]